# Creating 15 different schema & CT in non-prod env and push it to prod env using tool

Tags: sites-9.5

How can i create more than 15 different schemas, CT based on a design in Sites 9.5 in non-prod env and then able to push it to prod env without manual?
What tool can i use to automate it?

Comment: Hi, this is a very broad question which is hard to answer. Nevertheless, I'm curious about your use case. Why are those 15 different Schemas & CTs not created manually through the UI? What does "based on a design" mean exactly; in what format is that design?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second part of your question (*which tool can I use to push Schemas & CTs from a non-production environment to a production environment?*): you can use Content Porter for that purpose.